# Setting Up Database/API For Persistent Login

Tags: android, iphone, database, security

I'm in charge of writing the server for a small start-up that is interested in writing a calendar sharing apps for Android, iPhone, etc.  The way we're going about this is using a public API that each mobile platform can use to login, update calendar, etc.  This will also make it easy if they want to extend their site for more functionality.  The scripts are written using PHP with a MySQL database.

Right now the flow of the app is user clicks the app icon:

if logged in previously then go to main screen,
else go to login screen

How should I design the database such that there is a 'Remember Me' option?  Should I just store a token on the server and locally and if they match then we know the user has logged in previously?  If the user has not selected the 'Remember Me' option, then when he exits the App a request is sent to the server to log him out?

What is the fastest, most secure, and easiest way to design this database?

Comment: Can you clarify the bit at end of question about "What is the fastest, most secure, and easiest way to design this database?" -- it's too vague and slightly confusing (e.g. do you mean runtime behaviour, or design stage?)

Comment: As in what tables, columns, and way I should set everything up.  I'm looking for something that is efficient in terms of space and runtime complexity but easily extendable at the same time.

Comment: use Sync API http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/aesync.html

Comment: isn't this just android specific?  I need something that's device independent.  That's why I figured I needed to roll my own.